# Where to look for historical or reconstructed orbit data for early NASA missions - Mercury-Atlas 6 for example

Tags: orbital-elements, project-mercury, two-line-elements, historical-data

After reading [this answer to *How many earth stations had astronauts on-site during John Glenn's orbit in Friendship-7?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19399/12102) I decided that for my own use I'd like to plot the orbit of Mercury-Atlas 6, the spacecraft piloted by John Glenn on February 20, 1962. This [thorough answer there](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19350/12102) lists fourteen (14) ground stations plus two additional radar tracking stations for telemetry and/or voice communication, spread out - roughly along the general path that the spacecraft wold follow.

Wikipedia's [Mercury-Atlas 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-Atlas_6) lists some parameters for an elliptical orbit in geocentric (inertial) coordinates. From these I should be able to find an ellipse whose ground track *comes close* to intersecting the launch and landing coordinates. There's some uncertainty there, but I'll see what happens tomorrow.

```
Perigee:       149 kilometers (80 nautical miles)
Apogee:        248 kilometers (134 nautical miles)
Inclination:   32.5 degrees
Launch site:   Cape Canaveral LC-14
Landing site:  21°20′N 68°40′W
```

While the TLE catalog available from [space-track.org](https://www.space-track.org/#/catalog) is convenient to use and indeed lists `SatCat: 1962-003A`, `NORAD: 00240`, it doesn't seem to have TLEs available. I requested data from the [Celestrak "requestor"](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/archives/request.asp) and have now received a second e-mail with the attached `.txt` file. No dice.

```
=====================================================================
  00240 1962-003A   MERCURY ATLAS 6                                  
  Launched: 1962-02-20 (051)           Start Date: 1962-02-19 (050)  
   Decayed: 1962-02-20 (051)            Stop Date: 1962-02-21 (052)  
=====================================================================
No data found for Catalog Number 00240
<End of file>
```

**Question:** Where to I look for historical or reconstructed orbit data for early NASA missions - Mercury-Atlas 6 for example.

Of course if there are more missions that would be great! I thought that I'd read years ago that NASA had put a collection of at least approximate, reconstructed trajectories somewhere for the public to access, but I can't find it now. I'm flexible on the form of the data, for example a table of state vectors, TLEs, or even one or more sets of Kepler orbital elements.

I suppose when I am done I can generate something like this display board shown below, but now I will also be able to plot approximate altitude, azimuth, and distance to each of the tracking stations as a function of time.

I'm not looking for such a plot, the answer I'm looking for will help suggest where I might find reconstructed orbit data.

[image: View of Mercury Control at Cape Canaveral Air Force Station, in Florida (USA) during the Mercury-Atlas 6 mission, in February 1962]

**above:** View of Mercury Control at Cape Canaveral Air Force Station, in Florida (USA) during the Mercury-Atlas 6 mission, in February 1962. From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mercury_Control_Center_during_Mercury-Atlas_6_mission_1962.jpg).

[image: A ground-track map for Mercury-6 from https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/SP-45/fig8.1.htm]

**above:** A ground-track map for Mercury-6 from [here](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/SP-45/fig8.1.htm).

Comment: Here is a better image: http://history.nasa.gov/SP-6/ch2.htm see Figure 2-1. But this is for the second orbital flight MA-7 with astronaut Carpenter.

Another image here http://science.ksc.nasa.gov/history/mercury/ma-6/docs/ma-6-results.pdf page 6 of PDF, figure 1-1. This is for MA-6 with John Glenn. But I found no numerical orbit elements.

Comment: Here is a lot of information about MA-6 http://www.ibiblio.org/mscorbit/document.html but I did not found orbital elements yet.

Comment: The MA-6 Technical Report on http://www.ibiblio.org/mscorbit/document.html shows some trajectory parameters in Table II on page 26 to 28 of PDF

A nice mixture of nautical and statue miles, velocities in foot per second. Good luck for the orbit plot.

Comment: A map with good quality: https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/SP-45/fig8.1.htm

Comment: Yippee - thanks @Uwe! Actually doing it this way is going to be much more fun. Now I've got to make sure I know what *space-fixed velocity* means. I am guessing that it's Earth-centered inertial, (ECI) and so the "Earth-fixed velocity" would be Earth-centered Earth-fixed (ECEF).  You have literally answered my question, maybe consider posting this info as an answer?

Comment: Reference points on that map: CAL = Goldstone Lake, CA; GYM = Guaymas, Mexico; WHS = White Sands, NM; TEX = Corpus Christi, TX; EGL = Eglin AFB, FL; BDA = Coopers Island, Bermuda; ATS = Atlantic Tracking Ship; CYI = Gran Canaria, Canary Islands; KNO = Kano, Nigeria; ZZB = Zanzibar; CSQ = USNS Coastal Sentry; MUC = Muchea, Australia; WOM = Woomera, Australia; CTN = Canton (Kanton) Island, Kiribati; HAW = Kauai, Hawaii.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record, @Uwe said this in a comment, which @uhoh considers an answer:

> The MA-6 Technical Report on http://ibiblio.org/mscorbit/document.html shows some trajectory parameters in Table II on page 26 to 28 of PDF A nice mixture of nautical and statue miles, velocities in foot per second. Good luck for the orbit plot

That [MA-6 Technical report](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mscorbaddon/MA6_TechnicalReport.pdf?download) says, for example:

`TABLE II COMPARISON OF PLANNED AND ACTUAL TRAJECTORY PARAMETERS
| Condition and Quantity              | Planned | Actual  | Difference |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Cutoff conditions (including tail-  |         |         |            |
|  off):                              |         |         |            |
| Range time, seconds                 | 303.3   | 302.0   | -1.3       |
|             min:sec                 | 05.03.3 | 05:02   |            |
| Geodetic latitude,                  | 30.4273 | 30.4533 |  0.0260    |
| Longitude, deg west                 | 72.5268 | 72.5865 |  0.0597    |
| Altitude, feet                      | 528,428 | 528,381 |     -47    |
|           nautical miles            |   57.00 |   56.96 |   -0.04    |
| Range, nautical miles               | 436.4   | 433.7   |    -2.7    |
| Space-fixed velocity, feet per sec  | 25715   | 26708   |    -7.0    |
| Space-fixed flight-path angle, deg  |     0   | -.0468  |  -.0468    |
| Space-fixed heading angle, deg      |         |         |            |
|   east of north                     | 77.4756 | 77.4826 |   0.0070   |`

The original memo on calculating orbits like Glenn's (by [Katherine Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katherine_Johnson), with Ted Skopinski, is [The Determination of Azimuth Angle at Burnout for Placing a Satellite over a Selected Earth Position 1960. T.H. Skopinski, Katherine G. Johnson, NASA TN D-233](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19980227091.pdf).

As I note there, I'd also love to see recreations of the orbits, and especially comparisons of the orbits calculated according to the original methods (including the IBM 7090 approach), vs modern [spacecraft kernel approaches](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/spiceconcept.html).

For more on recreations of what those human computers, of Hidden Figures fame, did, see my answer at [specific examples of the calculations human “computers” did for the Mercury space program?](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20870/5775).

These data, showing state vectors for images (position, direction of view) from Apollo may also be of interest.

- [Apollo Image Archive - Ephemeris Data](http://apollo.sese.asu.edu/EPHEMERIS/)

Comment: This seems to be really interesting - I will take a day or two to look through it  and try to take it all in - thank you very much! I'd asked [an IBM 7090 ere question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19582/12102), but I hadn't seen your answer, thanks for calling my attention to it!

Comment: @uhoh Thanks. I enjoyed that quest of yours on  Frenet frame and the Gram–Schmidt process too!

Comment: fyi I've just asked [If I wanted to reconstruct an entire Apollo mission's crewed spacecraft trajectories, what are the key sources of historical data I'd look for?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40074/12102)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't super helpful, but too long for a comment: you might look the archived PDS SPK files at: http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/data_operational.html

More specific links:

- http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/data_lunar.html includes a little bit of Apollo 15 from 1971.
- http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/ is the whole list of missions. Mercury/Atlas isn't in the list, but some other older missions are.
- http://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/data_pds_archived.html is a general reference to older data.

Poke around the site a bit more: you probably won't find Mercury Atlas, but might other interesting missions.

Comment: OK got-em. Yes, there are some interesting things in there, thanks!

Comment: fyi I've just asked [If I wanted to reconstruct an entire Apollo mission's crewed spacecraft trajectories, what are the key sources of historical data I'd look for?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40074/12102)