# If a spacecraft is orbiting around the Moon, what direction would the nadir axis be?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, astrodynamics

Nadir for a craft orbiting the Earth would be radially in, is nadir always pointed towards the Earth or is it pointed towards the celestial body that the craft is orbiting?

Comment: slightly related but not a duplicate; [In “spacecraft talk” is nadir just a fancy word for “down”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19727/12102) I assume it's the 2nd option "towards the celestial body the craft is revolving about" but I can't thing of a good way to support that.

Comment: Actually not all spacecraft have fixed attitude to Earth during flight. For example. Soyuz is spin-stabilised during 2-day transfer to ISS http://blogs.esa.int/iriss/2015/09/03/spinning-the-soyuz/

Answer (score 3):

Nadir is always pointed down to the object below. In more rigorous terms the nadir at a given point is the local vertical direction pointing in the direction of the force of gravity at that location. (see for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadir?wprov=sfla1) , [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nadir))

For a satellite orbiting the moon, the nadir vector would point at the moon surface. For a satellite orbiting Mars it would point at the Mars surface.

Comment: @uhoh ok, added some sources