# What are some specific examples of the calculations human "computers" did for the Mercury space program?

Tags: history, mathematics, project-mercury, computing

The movie *[Hidden Figures](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Figures)* tells the story of three black women who were "computers" for the Mercury space program. They performed calculations related to  orbits, launches, aerodynamics, etc.

What are some specific examples of the calculations they did? In what form would they receive a problem, and what would their completed work look like? Are there are any examples of their original work publicly available? The level of detail I'm looking for is such that I could, if I wanted, spend a day replicating a piece of work they did.

Comment: Nice question. As shown in the movie, the Mercury program seems to have happened during a time when they were transitioning from human computers to electronic computers. (Apparently the story about Shepard wanting Katherine Goble to check the IBM calculations by hand is true.) So it might be hard to know what was actually done by humans during Mercury. The movie also depicts the data as being secret and being given to Goble in heavily redacted form, so I don't know if they're now publicly available.

Comment: "Spend **a day**" might be a limiting constraint. Calculating precise trajectories by hand probably involves some fairly specific techniques that may no longer be needed with the advent of modern computers. It may take  weeks to even locate information on, read, and understand these techniques before spending *a day* reproducing them. See for example [this answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/19601/12102) by @DavidHammon.

Comment: @BenCrowell Glenn, not Shepard.

Comment: [Katherine Johnson's paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19980227091.pdf) will give you some idea of the kinds of calculations they did.

Comment: Reading Katherin Johnson's paper I guess they used tables of trigonometric functions and logarithmic tables for calculations. There are results with 5 to 6 and even 7 decimal places, this was not possible using slide rules. But I wonder if the needed tables for such a precision were calculated by human computers too. If I have some hours free, I would like to calculate the given examples using a HP 32S RPN scientific calculator. But may be I should use Excel instead.

Comment: There is a very interesting sentence in Katherin Johnson's paper:
  
"The results for both cases are then compared with the results obtained by the method of reference 2 of a three-degree-of-freedom calculation for an oblate rotating earth performed on an IBM 704 electronic data processing machine."
  
It seems they really compared results of human computers with the results of electronic computers, but they used a more complex model for the electronic computation.

Comment: Note that there were also mechanical desktop computing machines.

Comment: The mechanical desktop computing machines may be used for addition, subtraction, multiplication and divison. But for trigonometric functions you need tables. Using a series expansion formula in a non programmable mechanical computing machine would be hard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(This is adapted from my question/answer at [Day-to-day tasks of human computers, ala Hidden Figures movie - History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5616/day-to-day-tasks-of-human-computers-ala-hidden-figures-movie/5779#5779))

I was also fascinated by the film [Hidden Figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Figures), and a related article from New Scientist magazine "[Gifted and black: The brilliant woman who got the US into space](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg23331090-400-gifted-and-black-the-incredible-woman-who-got-the-us-into-space/?utm_source=NSNS)".

**Compressible Flow**

In the article I found an example of the sort of calculations that these amazing human computers carried out. It is from https://crgis.ndc.nasa.gov/crgis/images/b/b7/CompressibleFlow.pdf, which is signed at the bottom "nmg - 2-3-53". *Hmmm - I wonder who that was, and how this fit in to the work at the time*.

First, I put together a modern re-working of it, with a [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) notebook and [Python](https://www.python.org/) code. A bit of it is below, and you can see the whole thing, and the IPython notebook behind it, at my gist:

- [Hidden Figures Example: Compressible Flow Equations and Table in Jupyter, Python](https://gist.github.com/nealmcb/a48efd1c4bc1276865e39d22ea69be0b)

A bit of googling turned up some relevant background material on the math itself, which includes:

- [Flow through a nozzle - Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304440/flow-through-a-nozzle)
- [Equations for the Design of Two-Dimensional Supersonic Nozzles - Report No. 907](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19930091974) from 1948

---

$M = { V \over a} $

${H - p \over q}
 = {F_c}
 = {1 + \eta} 
 = { {2 \over {\gamma M^2}} { \left[{( {1 + {{\gamma - 1} \over 2}} M^2)}^{\gamma \over {\gamma - 1} } - 1\right]} } 
 = {1.42857 \over M^2} \left[(1 + 0.2 M^2) ^ {3.5} - 1\right] $

...

`M       H−p/q   T/T0    A1/A    rho/rho0 Psonic     p/H     q/H 
0.001   1.0000  1.0000  0.0017  1.0000  -673870.092 1.0000  0.00000
0.002   1.0000  1.0000  0.0035  1.0000  -168467.127 1.0000  0.00000
0.003   1.0000  1.0000  0.0052  1.0000  -74873.985  1.0000  0.00001
...`

**Orbits**

The first memo, on orbit determination, that [Katherine Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katherine_Johnson) did, with a co-worker, is [The Determination of Azimuth Angle at Burnout for Placing a Satellite over a Selected Earth Position 1960. T.H. Skopinski, Katherine G. Johnson, NASA TN D-233](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19980227091.pdf)

This example from the (most excellent) [Hidden Figures book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Figures_(book)) provides some details of the actual computations that she did, checking the [IBM 7090](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_7090) trajectory calculations for the first US orbital mission. E.g. she was working to 8 significant digits:

> [Katherine Johnson] worked thru every minute of what was programmed to be [John Glenn's] three-orbit mission, coming up with numbers for eleven different output variables, each computed to eight significant digits.  It took a day and a half.

*Update: See more on Glenn's orbit here:* [Where to look for historical or reconstructed orbit data for early NASA missions - Mercury-Atlas 6 for example](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19402/5775)

**Equipment**

The book also notes that the human computers used mechanical calculators. Some great detail on their working environment comes from a 1942 memo reproduced in [Hidden Figures and Human Computers | National Air and Space Museum](https://airandspace.si.edu/stories/editorial/hidden-figures-and-human-computers), including these brief excerpts:

> ... the work of a computer required skill and judgment. Computers gathered data by reading pressure values from manometers placed in the wind tunnel. Depending on the application, the data were smoothed, plotted, and interpolated. Data reduction and analysis were carried out with the help of [calculators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_calculator#1900s_to_1970s), slide rules, [planimeters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planimeter), drafting tools, and other instruments. The women in these roles knew how to organize computational work and how to do so quickly without making mistakes. This knowledge was unique to them....

...

> The automatic computing machines and [Comptometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comptometer) cost over $500.00 each....
>
> The automatic calculator is usually the Friden or Marchant.... The computers were also furnished with 20 inch (log-log duplex) slide rules....
>
> ... for the type of computer who has some mathematical background the type of work required of her could probably be better done on the calculating machine....
>
> Each computing section has one light-table for tracing purposes.... A set of five-place logarithmic tables and trigonometric tables is also provided, together with a few scale, triangle and French curves....

I wish the film had had just a bit more on those mechanical calculators. But I found a video of one of the models they used in action, a [1956 Friden STW 10 - Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKm9eM2BuM0) taking a square root.

**Type of Work**

One more excerpt:

> There is a large amount of simple calculation required in the work here at NACA. Most [wind] tunnels have means for taking photographs of banks of nearly a hundred manometers at a time. The computers read off the liquid levels and complete the analysis. On the other hand, some of the calculations are sent to the computers in the form of complicated formulas which necessitate a knowledge of trigonometry and sometimes of mathematics involving the calculus. In general, however, the group head would reduce this more complicated work down to tabular form requiring rather routine operations before it would  be given to the machine operator. Most of the work coming from the engineers is accompanied by a memo of calculating instructions or word-of-mouth explanations. The computers in any one section soon learn what the usual type of calculation required of them would be.

Many of the calculations which involved ordinary arithmetic could have been handled on the mechanical calculators. But I'm guessing that when it involved trigonometry or logarithms, they would have been using slide rules or looking results up in tables.  Tables which had, most likely, been computed years earlier by other human computers as part of the [Mathematical Tables Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Tables_Project).

And, as in the example I started with, they were creating their own tables for things like compressible flow, that others could in turn use in the future.

Comment: Great research, and thanks for sharing the notebook!

Comment: @MarkEichenlaub Thanks :)  What I really want to see (or maybe do) now is a replication of the orbit calculations, starting with implementing the equations and examples in Johnson's "Azimouth.." paper.  I wonder what the "eleven different output variables" were?

Comment: For the broader picture, see also the book, and video, by David Alan Grier, editor of IEEE Annals of History of Computing [When Computers Were Human: Talk for the Computer History Museum - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwqltwvPnkw)