# Is there an API for accessing old TLEs of non-historic objects?

Tags: simulation, two-line-elements, historical-data, api

There are various APIs online for accessing TLEs for a satellite object from CelesTrak. However, the APIs retrieved are usually the most recent ones generated.

There are also a lesser number of APIs for accessing stored TLE data for old historical satellites, such as those operated by NASA, ESA or Roscosmos.

Are there any APIs out there that provide access old (as old as possible) TLEs for non-historical satellites? I think Space-Track has some data, but I believe the only way to access that data is manually via the UI on the website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `https://space-track.org` which provides you with *pretty much* all publicly available TLEs since the beginning. You have to register with an email address and abide by their terms.

- [this answer to *Resources for number of orbiting and active satellites by year?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/45958/12102)
- [What was the first proper Two Line Element to be generated?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19887/12102)

Celestrak does have *some* legacy TLEs saved on special dedicated pages.

- [Why Celestrak has Archived TLEs for most space stations from Russia and the US, but not Tiangong-1, Tiangong-2 or Skylab?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30220/12102)

Comment: This seems to be the main (if not the only) option available for this application.

Comment: @jos I can't say for sure but it certainly does seem that way.