# What is/were the Soviet/Russian qualifications for a capsule communicator?

Tags: communication, russia, soviet-union, mission-control

The person in mission control responsible for speaking to American crews is called the capsule communicator or CAPCOM.  Historically this person has been another astronaut -- as they would have the same training as those on the mission and would best understand how an astronaut thinks -- although [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32092/26446) discusses some exceptions.

**Did/does the Soviet or Russian programs similarly use other cosmonauts for such a position?**  If not, how was a person chosen for this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flight Control Lead Operations Team](https://www.energia.ru/en/news/news-2013/news_10-10.html)  (Главная оперативная группа управления полётами[ГОГУ]):

> Specialists from RSC Energia after S.P. Korolev, MCC of TsNII of Machinebuilding form the LOCT basis. The team also involves specialists from subcontracting enterprises-developers of space vehicles and stations onboard systems.

Structural scheme of ГОГУ:

[image]

Inside the red rectangle - "Group communication with the crew"

Cosmonauts were involved as consultants in different situations, like other technical or medical consultants. For [example](https://www.kik-sssr.ru/0_Moscow.htm):

> from notes in the logbook V.V. Tereshkova follows that her comrades in the cosmonaut corps, namely candidates for the next flights: NIP-12 to Kolpashevo - D. Zaikin, could negotiate with her on VHF radio communication Zarya. NIP-10 in Simferopol - V. Gorbatko. NIP-14 in Schelkovo-7 - P. Belyaev (it is interesting that two years later, during the flight of Voskhod-2, she herself kept in touch with A. Leonov and P. Belyaev from here).
>
> On  “Vesna” Short Waves communications  from the Novosibirsk radio center - G. Shonin, from the Almaty radio center - V. Varlamov. From the Sverdlovsk Radio Center - V. Komarov. Also in touch were: at NIP-13 in Ulan-Ude - Air Force representative Lieutenant Colonel G. Titarev, in Moscow - Air Force Colonel Terentyev, in Khabarovsk - Air Force Colonel Mikhail Petrovich Kadushkin, in the Kiev Radio Center - medical service colonel E. Karpov and other representatives of Cosmonaut Training Center.
> [image]

Examples of dialogs between crew of the orbital station and Flight Control Lead Operations Team are in the articles of the Sven Grahn site, for example  - [Salvaging Salyut 7](http://www.svengrahn.pp.se/trackind/Salyut7/SalvaSal7.htm)

You can read more about history of ГОГУ in Russian:

[Space Flight Management Service](https://www.kik-sssr.ru/00.10_Serv_kontrol_SF.htm)

[Flight Control Lead Operations Team (GOGU): HISTORY OF CREATION AND ACTIVITY](http://readings.gmik.ru/lecture/2009-GLAVNAYA-OPERATIVNAYA-GRUPPA-UPRAVLENIYA-GOGU-ISTORIYA-SOZDANIYA-I-DEYATELNOSTI)

[80 years to cosmonaut Eliseev Alexei Stanislavovich - one of the founders of the Flight Control Lead Operations Team](https://gagarin.energia.ru/past-future/229-intervyu-s-v-d-blagovym.html)